# How windows progran can transmit an input and get an output to an FPGA

Tags: fpga

I am new to programming and FPGA. I like to run a program on my windows 10 PC and like to send input to the FPGA and when processing is done I like to receive output to the same program. Is it possible and how it can be achieved. I need some direction to start finding a way.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to buy a Digilent Arty A7 board. It is low cost and very nice to work with.
To communicate with a PC/Windows you can use the USB to UART that you have on that board. However I think the best and easiest way to do it is to use an IP core that has support for Ethernet and TCP/IP. Using TCP/IP is very simple on the PC side using Python, Matlab, Telnet or any programming tool.
The best IP for the Xilinx FPGA that I have found so far is the ones from [fpga-cores.com](http://www.fpga-cores.com/). There you only have to implement an AXI4 Stream to communicate with the client. I don't think it gets easier than that. 
That core also include remote programming of the FPGA over Ethernet and a logic analyzer. All that is for free.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. A lot of people ask about data processing on FPGA but never think about how to get the data to and from it. (Until it is too late)

The best way is to find an FPGA which has also has an SOC. That is: a processor, DDR interface and one or more high speed interfaces. Ethernet, USB, PCIe. Make sure they come with complete working example code, often some RTOS.
As to which FPGA to choose greatly depends on what you want it to do. You also need to have enough programmable gates to implement the function you want.

Nowadays all vendors have free HDL compilers up to a certain size FPGA. 
Every FPGA manufacturer also has one or more prototyping boards, but the price of those varies a lot.

If you have some FPGA code which is capable of very high data throughput your interface is likely to become the bottleneck.
A PCIe board offers the highest data throughput, but for that you need to have matching drivers on both the FPGA board and the PC. In that case check that it has example drivers for the PC side too.
<sub>Yes, I fell into that trap a few years back</sub>